# Translate openssl console command to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, openssl

I've setup proftpd with a tutorial in an Ubuntu Server machine with MySQL user access. Now I've created some users (`user01`, `user02`, `user03`) and created a cyphered password with this command:

```
/bin/echo "{md5}"`/bin/echo -n "mypassword" | openssl dgst -binary -md5 | openssl enc -base64`
{md5}NIGde+6ruSYKXIVLyFs+RA==
```

I'm not ashamed to say I did not understand anything of this command, but I would like to, and make the same command line work in a PHP code.
I know there is an OpenSSL library in PHP, but I don't really know how to get the same result.

Comment: It's actually quite a pain to take what an openssl command does and break it down to all of the steps.  The last time I had to do this, with any language, it involved deep digging in the openssl source code.  And that assumes the PHP openssl libs expose all of the necessary functions.  I don't normally recommend shelling out to juts call commands, but in this case I would strongly encourage you to go that route vs. trying to implement all of this in straight PHP.

Comment: I'm not sure if OpenSSL should go on the title. Normally, tags are not necessary in the title (much less *newbie*), but please adjust as you see fit to get a descriptive organic title.

Comment: The only thing I need is to get "{md5}NIGde+6ruSYKXIVLyFs+RA==" as result of encrypting "mypassword"

Answer (score 1):

I've found it out my self (and I feel proud about)

```
    `//php
    $dgst = openssl_digest('mypassword', 'md5', TRUE);
    echo "{md5}" . base64_encode($dgst); `
```

This will give as result '{md5}NIGde+6ruSYKXIVLyFs+RA=='

Answer (score 0):

```
echo base64_encode(md5('mypassword', true));
```

No need to even use the openssl extension.